# 18.04 Chrome, spotify (Deb package) and snap lost sound, Firefox works

Tags: sound, firefox, google-chrome, 18.04

I saw Ubuntu discovered all my sound devices and volume control-able but I have no sound ...

Tried to reinstall pulse audio & alsa.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

fixed:

```
killall pulseaudio
rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ~/.pulse*
```